# Serverless Django app (AWS Lambda via Zappa) times out when trying to OAuth to Twitter

Tags: django, twitter, aws-lambda, oauth, zappa

I've got a Django app setup to use `django-allauth` to connect to Twitter. The flow is all working locally and I've followed the same setup steps on Lambda to add my tokens, site, etc.

When I try to access the login url (`/accounts/twitter/login/`) the request eventually times out with this message from AWS Lambda:

```
{"message": "Endpoint request timed out"}
```

The last message from `zappa tail` before the timeout event is:

```
[1619019159940] [DEBUG] 2021-04-21T15:32:39.939Z 7f66a0e3-58de-4612-82c0-54590d69676f Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.twitter.com:443
```

I've seen that the gateways have a 30 second timeout but I don't think it should be taking this long anyway. Locally, it's taking a couple of seconds.

Does anyone with knowledge of these platforms have an idea where the bottleneck might be and where the issue could be? Or have any pointed questions to help debug?

Things I've already checked and (tentatively) ruled out:

- The database backend is AWS Aurora Serverless, and I did worry that the double-serverless setup might be causing the slow speeds. However, a simple call of the Django management command (`zappa manage dev migrate` returns takes less than a second so I've ruled that out for now. Plus the Admin dashboard loads fine which is also accessing the DB.
- I've got both the dev and live URLs added into Twitter's dashboard as valid OAuth callback URLs.

Comment: Did you try with [AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html) to identify your performance bottleneck?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of that feature. I'll check and post any useful results if it doesn't resolve it completely.

Comment: Nothing useful in there, sadly. I have been viewing the logs live whilst testing and it's the same messages about the failed Twitter request.

Comment: Is your Lambda in a VPC. This has nothing to do with "performance". This is a network issue.

Comment: @Jens yes it is, good point. I had assumed the fact I was able to connect via web that the lambda would also be able to make outbound connections. I’ll look into whether I need to allow outbound connections on 80 and 443.

Comment: @Jens you were right, it's the fact that I'm operating in a VPC (required for AWS RDS serverless DBs). You need to setup extra services like a NAT Gateway to access public internet. This defeats the object of going serverless for this app, because these are per-hour billing so I'll look into alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this answer to help future searches, although it's not the route I'll take.

Thanks to @Jens in the comments for pointing towards the VPC issue. You need to add a NAT Gateway service to the Lambda to add public internet access to a private VPC.

> "To grant internet access to your function, its associated VPC must have a NAT gateway (or NAT instance) in a public subnet."

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

This is a per-hour billed extra so might defeat the point of using serverless (if you're using it for small fees and simplicity rather than scale like I was).

Comment: Please accept your answer as the answer to your question. This is allowed.

Comment: @Jens thanks, I will do once the timer allows it tomorrow.